# Authorization on webapi

Tags: magento2, webapi

I have built a custom webapi endpoind with which a customer can get details of their personalised item.

```
    <route url="/V1/personalizations/get/:personalizationId" method="GET">
        <service class="Me\MyPersonalization\Api\PersonalizationRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

This works great and I can retrieve individual Personalization Objects.

The problem is however, anyone can retrieve anyone elses row as there is no logic to check if the logged in user owns the row.

I can easily do something in the get() method to check....

```
if ($this->customerSession->getCustomerId() !== $personalization->getCustomerId()) {
    throw new LocalizedException(__("You are not allowed to do this"));
}
```

But I would need to repeat the logic for every method.

What is the correct way to do custom authentication on webapi?

Comment: Good Question! how many other methods are we talking about? If this a CRUD repository I'd say copy the copy. Maybe wrap it in a method so you can modify it easier.

Comment: checkout magentos code https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/etc/webapi.xml